# How do I add a tab to a given tabcontrol.?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I am using VS2010 (C#) and I want to create a button that creates a new tab. I already have a `tabControl` container created. How would I do this?

Comment: What are you using? Winforms, WPF or something else?

Comment: @Otiel: I could not post it as an answer because of a score of less than 100.

Answer (score 1):

Moved here from Brandon's solution in the question:

```
string title = "TabPage " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
```